# Logo in \titlegraphic not showing

Tags: tikz-pgf, posters, tikzposter

I am trying to add a logo instead of a title in my poster using `\titlegraphic`, but unfortunately the logo is not displayed.

Any idea of what is going wrong?

```
\documentclass[22pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=20mm, innermargin=5mm, blockverticalspace=0mm, colspace=5mm, subcolspace=0mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\definecolorstyle{color}{
    \definecolor{C-BrightBlue}{HTML}{00a1df}
}
{
    \colorlet{titlefgcolor}{white}
}
\usecolorstyle{color}

\definetitlestyle{title}{
        width=0.98\textwidth, 
        linewidth=0pt,
        roundedcorners=15, 
        innersep=10pt, 
        titletotopverticalspace=2mm, 
        titletoblockverticalspace=10mm}
{
        \draw[color=black, 
            line width=5pt, 
            fill=C-BrightBlue, 
            rounded corners=\titleroundedcorners,
            drop shadow=gray] 
        (\titleposleft,\titlepostop) rectangle (\titleposright,\titleposbottom);
}
\usetitlestyle{title}

\definebackgroundstyle{background}{
    \draw[inner sep=0pt, line width = 0pt, color=white](bottomleft) rectangle (topright);
}
\usebackgroundstyle{background}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.2\colwidth]{image.pdf}}
\author{\large \sffamily List of authors.}
\institute{\Large \sffamily List of institutions}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a smaller example that both demonstrates the problem and identifies the cause:

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.2\colwidth]{example-image}}
\author{\the\colwidth} % \the\colwidth prints the value of \colwidth
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, at the time the title is typeset, the `\colwidth` length is not set to anything useful, and is 0pt. Images that are 0pt wide are quite hard to see.

Use e.g. `\textwidth`, `\paperwidth`, or an explicit length like `5cm` instead.

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\titlegraphic{%
\includegraphics[width=0.1\paperwidth]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
}
\author{\the\colwidth}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that was stupid. Thank you very much for spotting it so quickly!